# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_DNUMBER in /home/a3206525/public_html/easymailer/inc/db_wrapper.php on line 6

Tags: php

I'm quite new on PHP coding and would like to see If it's possible to get help of the code below. Apparently the error is only on line 6.

```
<?php
class DBWrapper
{   
    function DBWrapper($server,$db,$user,$pass)
    {        
        $this->Server = $server;
        $this->DB = $db;
        $this->User = $user;
        $this->Password = $pass;

        mysql_connect($this->Server, $this->User, $this->password) or
                    die("Can't connect, please check your settings. Here is the MySQL error: ".mysql_error());

        mysql_select_db($this->DB) or
                    die("Can't select DB, please check your settings. Here is the MySQL error: ".mysql_error());       
    }
```

I really hope to receive some help about this.

Comment: You should not post your username and password etc..

Comment: Your code makes no sense at all!

Comment: You've obviously changed those from $server, etc. change them back and find the correct place to change them.

Comment: Flagged for moderator attention to get a developer to remove the username/password: http://puu.sh/e6J9f/1bc72aeb79.png

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea True, but even if they didn't do so this question is still VLQ for not having a clear problem statement. The question will probably be removed, the OP is probably under a question-ban by now.

Comment: @cybermonkey sorry, I deleted my comment because I didn't realise they meant post them on the question rather than posting from a html form!

Comment: I advise you to change your password

Comment: @beauXjames, your edit is a substantive change to the question. Whilst it is a good idea for us to help an OP hide their leaked credentials, it is also a good idea to avoid changing the meaning of code samples. (Now the creds are posted, the OP should just change them anyway).

Comment: I've deleted this question, pending removal of the edit history items by a Stack Exchange developer. It will likely be restored after that. I **do** still *strongly* recommend you change the login information on the server right away, @Bruno

Comment: @halfer, it was actually an attempt to edit the question in the line of review...was punching through a few that day...apologies

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
    $this->Server = $mysql3.000webhost.com;
```

You have no quotes on this "string", so it's being parsed as:

```
$this->Sever = somevariable concatenate with undefined/illegal constant concatenate with undefined constant
```

Perhaps

```
    $this->Server = '$mysql3.000webhost.com';
```

or something?

Comment: I think it should just be $this->Server = $Server e.d.

Comment: maybe, but that's up to OP to clarify.

Comment: I've deleted this question, pending removal of the edit history items by a Stack Exchange developer. It will likely be restored after that.

Answer (score 1):

```
    $this->Server = $#####;
    $this->DB = $#####;
    $this->User = $######;
    $this->Password = $#######;
```

Hmm, aren't those strings? If so, skip `$` and put them into `'`.

```
    $this->Server = 'mysql3.000webhost.com';
    $this->DB = 'a3206525_ezmail';
    $this->User = 'a3206525_ezmail';
    $this->Password = 'belfegor666';
```

Also, it's not wise to publish your credentials ;)

And the most important advice, read some more about PHP. It'll really help you.

Comment: awesome! and thank you! (') this did the trick ;) thanks also for the advice, I got a bit stressed out and forgot to cleanup the credentials  :/